# Filtering Numpy's array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

Working with a numpy's ndarray for preprossessing data to a neural network. It basically contains several fixed-length arrays for sensor data. So for example:

```
>>> type(arr)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> arr.shape
(400,1,5,4)

>>> arr
 [
  [[ 9.4 -3.7 -5.2  3.8]
   [ 2.8  1.4 -1.7  3.4]
   [ 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0]
   [ 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0]
   [ 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0]]
  ..
  [[ 0.0 -1.0  2.1  0.0]
   [ 3.0  2.8 -3.0  8.2]
   [ 7.5  1.7 -3.8  2.6]
   [ 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0]
   [ 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0]]
 ]
```

Each of the nested array is shaped `(1, 5,4)`. The goal is to run through this `arr` and select only those arrays having at least the first three rows as non-zero (although single entry can be zero, but not whole row).

So in the example I give above, the first nested array should be deleted because only 2 first-rows are non-zero, whereas we need 3 and above.

Comment: So, what is the problem? The simplest way to do is to check every row for every matrix in `arr`. Although you can use alternative ways, but it will be quite easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a trick you can use:

```
mask = arr[:,:,:3].any(axis=3).all(axis=2)
arr_filtered = arr[mask]
```

Quick explanation: To keep a nested array it should have at least 3 first rows (hence we need to look only at `arr[:,:,:3]`) such that all of them (hence `.all(axis=2)` at the end) have at least one non-zero entry (hence `.any(axis=3)`).

Comment: Serious, when can I be a master of python? Thank you so much for the precise and clear explanation.